# Store all elements of an array to another array in order to process

Tags: c, hardware

I have got a problem with proccessing all elements of an array. I have two different arrays ( `x[]` and `y[]` ), each one has 40000 elements. I have used the Sliding Window to sweep 5 elements from each one in order to compute Cross Correlation between blocks (5 elements of `x[]` and 5 elements of `y[]`). After computing, it will continuously sweep to second Window .. and to the end of an array. How can I get the results of Correlation and store it in new array?. The inputs are `gc_us_dist_data` and `gc_us_prox_data` and I would like to receive an array of results when computing Correlation. Hope to receive the help from everybody.

```
    const int16_t gc_us_dist_data[SAMPLES] //4000 SAMPLES
    const int16_t gc_us_prox_data[SAMPLES] //4000 SAMPLES
    /* This function is real implementation of the sliding window algorithm */
        int slide_window_01(int buffer1[], int N, int buffer_len){

        int i = 0, j = 0, s;
        int16_t dist[SAMPLES];

        for(j=0 ; j + N < buffer_len; j++){
          /* Window starts at index 0 and is of size N */
          // printf("\nCurrent window :");
           for(s =j; s<j+N; s++){
                dist[SAMPLES] = buffer1[s];
           }
        }
    }

        int slide_window_02(int buffer2[], int N, int buffer_len){

            int i = 0, j = 0, s;
            int16_t prox[SAMPLES];

            for(j=0 ; j + N < buffer_len; j++){
                /* Window starts at index 0 and is of size N */
                // printf("\nCurrent window :");
                for(s =j; s<j+N; s++){
                    prox[SAMPLES] = buffer2[s];
                }
            }
        }
     /*------------- Cross Correlation between two signals -----------------------
      ---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    //  x = gc_us_dist_data, y = gc_us_prox_data 

    int correlation(int dist[], int prox[]){

        int xy[SAMPLES], xsquare[SAMPLES], ysquare[SAMPLES];
        int i, xsum, ysum, xysum, xsqr_sum, ysqr_sum;
        float coeff[SAMPLES], num, deno;

        xsum = ysum = xysum = xsqr_sum = ysqr_sum = 0;

        /* find the needed data to manipulate correlation coeff */
        for (i = 0; i < SAMPLES; i++)
        {
            xy[i] = dist[i] * prox[i];
            xsquare[i] = dist[i] * dist[i];
            ysquare[i] = prox[i] * prox[i];
            xsum = xsum + dist[i];
            ysum = ysum + prox[i];
            xysum = xysum + xy[i];
            xsqr_sum = xsqr_sum + xsquare[i];
            ysqr_sum = ysqr_sum + ysquare[i];
        }

        num = 1.0 * ((SAMPLES * xysum) - (xsum * ysum));
        deno = 1.0 * ((SAMPLES * xsqr_sum - xsum * xsum)* (SAMPLES * ysqr_sum - ysum * ysum));

        /* calculate correlation coefficient */
        for(int i=0; i < SAMPLES; i++)
        {
            coeff[i] = num / sqrt(deno);
        }

    }

int main(void)
{
int16_t buffer1[SAMPLES], dist[SAMPLES];
    int16_t buffer2[SAMPLES], prox[SAMPLES];
    memcpy(&buffer1, &gc_us_dist_data, sizeof buffer1); //copy all elements to buffer
    memcpy(&buffer2, &gc_us_prox_data, sizeof buffer2 ); //copy all elements to buffer
    const int N = 5;
    int size1 = sizeof(buffer1)/ sizeof(buffer1[0]);
    int size2 = sizeof(buffer2)/ sizeof(buffer2[0]);
    slide_window_01(buffer1,N,size1);
    slide_window_02(buffer2,N,size2);

    correlation(dist, prox);
}
```

Comment: What problem are you facing?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on "[t]he code is not working"? *How* is it not working? Does it not build? Does it crash? Do you get unexpected results? Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I can not get the results of the function Correlation(), I would like to receive a result of Correlation after computing each block (Sliding Window for x[] and y[])

Comment: Your `correlation` function seems to use all SAMPLES for calculation. However, your textual description says that it is done over 5 elements.

Comment: @4386427 you are right, but the problem that I donot have a connection between getting datas from `slide_window_01`and `slide_window_02`into `correlation`function to compute values.

Comment: @HuỳnhNgọcTân - Do you just want to calculate correlation over N elements like this: a) element 0..N-1, b) element 1..N, c) element 2..N+1 ? In that case it is very simple and your code is making it much more difficult than needed.

Comment: @4386427 if it is possible displaying the results of correlation, i would like to see how it works.

Answer (score 0):

`slide_window_01` and `slide_window_02` does nothing that are visible after the function calls.

You just fill values into a local array (e.g. `int16_t dist[SAMPLES];`) which is lost as soon as the function returns.

The local array `int16_t dist[SAMPLES];` in the function has nothing to do with the `dist[SAMPLES]` in main. So - in other words - the variable in main does **not** change when you call the function.

This also means that you call `correlation` with an uninitialized array, i.e. you won't get any meaningful result (in fact you have undefined behavior).

In the function you have

```
dist[SAMPLES] = buffer1[s];
```

this is illegal as the valid indexes are `0 ... SAMPLES-1`

The function `correlation` doesn't return anything either. All results are stored locally so the results is lost when the function returns.

If you want a function to modify an array all you need is to pass the array which is done as a pointer.

A simple example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void incrementArray(int* dst, int* src, int size)
{
    int i;
    for (i=0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        dst[i] = src[i] + 1;
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
    int i;
    int x[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    int result[5];

    // Print start values for x
    for (i=0; i<5; ++i)
    {
        printf("%d ", x[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    // Call function 
    incrementArray(result, x, 5);

    // Print result
    for (i=0; i<5; ++i)
    {
        printf("%d ", result[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1 2 3 4 5 
2 3 4 5 6
```

Comment: I use slide_window_01 and slide_window_02 to get the element from each  one, and I push these elements from two functions (slide_window_01, slide_window_01) into the function of correlation to computing. But nothing happens.

Comment: I would like to get the datas in `slide_window_01`and `slide_window_02`and pushing them into `correlation`function to compute values. After that I can store the results in new array. But seemly the functions are not working.

Comment: @HuỳnhNgọcTân - No your functions are not working as they only writes to local variables.

Comment: How can i in the main function, i can call the function of Correlation to give me the results, and after that, I can store them into my new array? Moreover, in the `correlation` function I can get the values from `slide_window_01`and `slide_window_02`

Comment: Thank you @4386427 , I will try to use it